# Copy data from specific column from a large text file and paste in excel sheet column wise

Tags: python

I have data written in text file which is a result from a different program output..data looks like this

Program XYZ

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"test data"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test for xxx
Test by  xxx

Sensor Sensor Name   Units     values 
1        SenA1         N        1234   
2        SenA2         N        2345          
3        SenA3         N        4567
4        SenA4         N        7890 
5        SenA5         N        3456
6        SenA6         N        5678 
7        SenA7         N        1234
8        SenA8         N        8907
9        SenA9         N        5678
10       SenA10        N        3457 
11       SenB1         N        1234   
12       SenB2         N        2345          
13       SenB3         N        4567
14       SenB4         N        7890 
15       SenB5         N        3456
16       SenB6         N        5678 
17       SenB7         N        1234
18       SenB8         N        8907
19       SenB9         N        5678
20       SenB10        N        3457
21       SenC1         N        1234   
22       SenC2         N        2345          
23       SenC3         N        4567
24       SenC4         N        7890 
25       SenC5         N        3456
26       SenC6         N        5678 
27       SenC7         N        1234
28       SenC8         N        8907
29       SenC9         N        5678
30       SenC10        N        3457
```

The values for each sensor names A1..A10, B1..B10, C1..C10 are listed continuously. My requirement is to copy 'values' of each sensor name A1..A10, B1..B10, C1..C10 into an excel sheet column wise side by side instead of continuous values.

I tried to google it and got this piece of code, but this code reads the data line by line and prints in excel line by line instead of column wise.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = workbook.add_sheet('Test')

f = open('Testcase.txt','r')
data = f.readlines()

for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i].splitlines()

    for j in range(len(row)):
        ws.write(i,j,row[j])
workbook.save ('Test.xls')
f.close()
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that reads the file and compiles a list of the rows.  I don't want to install the Excel packages, so I just print the results, but presumably you can convert this to Excel sheets.

```
f = open('x.txt','r')

sense = [{} for _ in range(10)]
for line in f:
    if not line[0].isdigit():
        continue
    parts = line.split()
    col = parts[1][3]
    row = int(parts[1][4:])
    sense[row-1][col] = int(parts[3])

print(','.join(('index','A','B','C')))
for n,row in enumerate(sense):
    print(f"{n+1},{row['A']},{row['B']},{row['C']}")
```

Output:

```
index,A,B,C
1,1234,1234,1234
2,2345,2345,2345
3,4567,4567,4567
4,7890,7890,7890
5,3456,3456,3456
6,5678,5678,5678
7,1234,1234,1234
8,8907,8907,8907
9,5678,5678,5678
10,3457,3457,3457
```